# C - array manipulation console app terminated with status 0

Tags: c, arrays

My app is supposed to take a double array, find the average of elements of even columns, find the max value, compare average to max / 2 and rotate the matrix 90 degrees if  average > max / 2.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int M = 4, N = 4;

int ** rotateArr(int arr[4][4]) {
    int D[4][4];
    int i, n;
    for(i=0; i <= 4; i++ ){
        for(n =0; n <= 4; n++){
            D[i][n] = arr[n][M - i + 1];
        }
    }
    return D;
}
int getAvg(int arr[4][4]) {
    int sum = 0, num = 0;
    int i, n;
    for(i=0; i <= 4; i += 2){
        for(n=0; n <= 4; n++){
            sum += arr[i][n];
            num += 1;
        }
    }
    return sum/num;
}

int ** getMax(int arr[4][4]) {
    int maxa = arr[0][0];
    int i, n;
    for(i=0; i <= 4; i++){
        for(n=0;  n <= 4; n++){
            if (maxa < arr[i][n]){
                maxa = arr[i][n];
            }
        }
    }
    return maxa;
}

int main()
{

    int S[4][4] = { { 1, 4, 10, 3 }, { 0, 6, 3, 8 }, { 7, 10 ,8, 5 },  { 9, 5, 11, 2}  };
    int maxa = 0;
    float avg = 0;

    avg = getAvg(S);
    maxa = getMax(S);
    int i , n;
    if (avg > maxa/2){
        S[4][4] = rotateArr(S);
        for(i=0; i <= 4; i+=2){
            for(n=0 ; n <= 4; n++){
                    printf("%d", S[i][n]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

The app doesn't output anything and just ends on key press with

> Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 2 seconds)

Comment: Well, then it terminated successfully.

Comment: Do some debugging and find out where the problem is. Is the average calculated correctly? The maximum? The rotation? etc.

Comment: @H2CO3, doesn't output any info though

Comment: @interjay, how do I do that debugging? The problem is that it doesn't output anything

Comment: The best way is to run it in a debugger. If you don't know how it's also possible to add print statements, e.g. to print the calculated average.

Comment: `int[4][4]` and `int**` are not compatible. You can't just replace every array dimension with a pointer.

Comment: All the `for` loop iteration should be `for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)`, not including `i <= 4`. And subroutine `getMax` returns `int` not `int **`. Thirdly, `S[4][4] = rotateArr(S);` this call is improper.

Comment: @Euphe: Your code assumes that `int[4][4]` can become `int**`. Drop this assumption.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of problems with your code. For example:

- All your loops are of the form `for(i=0; i <= 4; i++ )` The condition should be changed to `i < 4` because the valid array indices are 0 to 3.
- The `rotateArr` function returns a pointer to a local variable. You can't do this. One solution is to receive the output array as a parameter and write into it:

  ```
  void rotateArr(int arr[4][4], int output[4][4]) {
       ....
       output[i][j] = ...;
  }
  ```
- `int**` is not the same as `int[4][4]`.
- `S[4][4] = ...` tries to assign to an invalid element. It looks like you're trying to assign to `S` itself, which can't be done (you need to assign each element, or `memcpy` from another array):

  ```
  int anArray[4][4];
  int anotherArray[4][4];
  memcpy(anArray, anotherArray, sizeof(anArray));
  ```
- In the expression `arr[n][M - i + 1]`, the second index can be out of range. Consider what happens when `i==0`.

I suggest you pay attention to compiler warnings, as they would catch some of these issues (on GCC compiler use the `-Wall` option). Also, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: I am newbie to C and I don't understand anything but your first point. How do I fix the other problems?

Comment: Beat me to it.
Also: `getMax`'s return type is `int **` but OP returns `int`

Comment: The compiler doesn't give any warnings. Could you please tell me how to fix problems? I already know that I have mistakes, thanks for telling me again. But what's the solution or where I can read about it?

Answer (score 1):

Analyse your program and you will find that;

1. You are returning `D` (of type `int (*)[4]` from `rotateArr` whose return type is `int **`. And similar issue with `getMax`.
2. For `n =4` array `arr[i][n]` will go out of bound!
3. `sum/num` is in fact not calculating the average value (numerator and denominator both are `int` and you will always get an `int` value (may be `0` too).
   and many more..........

Comment: @Euphe; For getting such warnings you should enable your `Wall` and `Wextra` flag in your compiler option.